# What is the best type of input for a 3D UNet?

Tags: image-segmentation, u-net, biology, 3d-convolution

I want to use 3D U-Net (or similar) network to create a 3D reconstruction of my microscopy data.

The original paper for the 3D U-Net (https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.06650) describes the implementation with orthogonal slices (xy, yz, zx planes) of the dataset used for training, which makes a lot of sense as the objective is to segment 3D objects in the data.

However, most implementations that I have come across online (github) use slices from the same plane (xy) for training. I am actually confused about how this works at all because it is not defining an object in its completeness. Can someone explain how this type of input works for 3D segmentation and if it can provide results comparable to the former?

(I understand that a lot of biological image acquisition is done in the form of continuous 2D slices in one plane across a z-stack and thus it might be more convenient to use the 2D slices as they are, but there are methods still to get the orthogonal slices from that too, right?)